# General and singular solution of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, singular-solution

How to find the general and singular solution of $3xy=2x^2\frac{dy}{dx}-2(\frac{dy}{dx})^2$. Please give me hints whether it can be solved or not. If yes, then how to proceed?

Comment: That's not a differential equation though.

Comment: $p=\frac{dy}{dx}$

Comment: Is $p=y'~~~~$ or?

Comment: Well, you can solve the equation for $y'$ in principle, provided you choose a branch of the solution. You get $y'=\frac{-2x^2 \pm \sqrt{4x^4-24xy}}{-4}$. Once you choose a sign, until $y=x^3/6$ you have a unique solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$3xy=2x^2\dfrac{dy}{dx}-2\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^2$

$y=\dfrac{2x}{3}\dfrac{dy}{dx}-\dfrac{2}{3x}\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^2$

Let $t=x^3$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{dy}{dt}\dfrac{dt}{dx}=3x^2\dfrac{dy}{dt}$

$\therefore y=2x^3\dfrac{dy}{dt}-6x^3\left(\dfrac{dy}{dt}\right)^2$

$y=2t\dfrac{dy}{dt}-6t\left(\dfrac{dy}{dt}\right)^2$